# What is process.env.BASE_URL in vue js?

Tags: vue.js

When I manually selected presets when installing vue using vue cli. I stumbled upon process.env.BASE_URL. I was tryng to find it in the internet but to no avail, I can't find any decent explanation.
Here's the code.

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})
```

Comment: you must have .env file in your root folder where you define value for BASE_URL

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the documentation is here 
https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables

It has a system of cascading files that will determine enviroment variables for your app.  The main file being a `.env`

The BASE_URL is semi arbitary, you could introduce your own BASE_ROUTER_URL variable if you wanted

Comment: I do not see any `.env` file in my project root. Where is it actually ?

Comment: via vue ui? I don't think it makes them by default, so just make it yourself.  Read the info in the link.  It has a pretty good description of how they work

Comment: no, i created the project via `vue create project_name`. No `.env` file in the project root. Then how could it use `process.env` in the router as said in OP ?

Comment: `BASE_URL` is not arbitrary. ([doc](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#using-env-variables-in-client-side-code)) `BASE_URL` - this corresponds to the `publicPath` option in `vue.config.js` and is the base path your app is deployed at.

Comment: you need to create the `.env` file yourself. You should have different `.env` file for production `.env` and development: `.env.development`. You need to use the `vue-cli-service serve --mode development` to run your project in development mode.