# Generate web.config file when running "npm run build"

Tags: vue.js

I have a Vue app served in IIS. I need the dist folder to have a custom web.config file as per instruction [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations). The problem I have now is whenever I run "npm run build", the whole dist folder gets nuked, and my web.config file is lost, and I need to create one again. Since the file is rather small, this isn't really a big of a deal but I really would like to automate this.

The way I work now is that I go to my test machine, git pull the main dev branch, execute "npm run build", create the web.config file and put it to the dist folder. I'm guessing I can do this in my CI/CD pipeline (I don't have one... yet), but I would like to know if there are any way to do this outside of CI/CD? Any way I can run "npm run build" and it'll automatically generate/copy a web.config file for me?

Comment: Put it in the `public` folder. Anything in there is copied as-is to the `dist` folder

Comment: Can't believe it's that simple... If you put it in the answer section, I will accept your answer :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vue CLI generated projects are configured to copy anything in the `public` folder directly into the build output directory (`dist` by default). They achieve this with the Webpack Copy plugin.

The only exception is the `index.html` file which undergoes some pre-processing to inject scripts and stylesheets before being copied.

With that in mind, put your `web.config` file in the `public` directory and it will be included verbatim in your builds.

Comment: Doing this will result in the pwa cache including the web.config as a file that the browser should request

Comment: @Blowsie, so I have the issue same as your comment, could you already fix it?

Comment: @Park try the answer in this post. [workbox webpack plugin exclude folder from precache manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55438555/283366)

Answer (score 2):

[@Phil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64709717) is simple and perfect if you have an invariant `web.config` file that does not need any variable expansion. However, if you'd like to generate a `web.config` file that includes, for example, an Rewrite rule with the `BASE_URL`, the following will work:

In `vue.config.js`:

```js
"use strict";

// Do NOT use the HtmlWebpackPlugin name to avoid a collision with standard Vue usage of the html-webpack-plugin
// NOTE also this uses the vue-cli-service dependency path for html-webpack-plugin
// Beware if the require() path is incorrect, it may fail silently, thus ignoring vue.config.js (per (per https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/5442)
const HtmlWebpackPlugin2 = require('@vue/cli-service/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    disableHostCheck: true,
  },
  transpileDependencies: ['vuetify'],
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? process.env.BASE_URL : '/',
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin2({  //  generate web.config
        title: 'web_config',
        template: 'src/web.config',
        filename: 'web.config',
        inject: false
      })
    ]
  }
}
```

A key element is to declare `const HtmlWebpackPlugin2 = require('@vue/cli-service/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin');` using a name **other than** `HtmlWebpackPlugin` to avoid clashing with the `vue-cli-service`'s use of `HtmlWebpackPlugin`. Then, in the `configureWebpack:` element, add the "new" `HtmlWebpackPlugin2` plugin with the `template` path to your `web.config` template. The `inject: false` option is also important to avoid injecting `<head>` and `<script>` tags into your `web.config` XML.

As noted in the OP's question, to run under IIS, the `web.config` file should include a rewrite rule that rewrites client-side routing paths to your virtual root (also described [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/tips-for-running-an-angular-app-in-iis/)). This can be accomplished with `html-webpack-plugin`'s variable expansion syntax `<%= process.env.MY_VARIABLE_NAME %>`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
            <rule name="SPA Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                <!-- match everything by default -->
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <!-- unless its a file -->
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <!-- or a directory -->
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    <!-- or is under the /api directory -->
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
                    <!-- list other routes or route prefixes here if you need to handle them server side -->
                </conditions>
                <!-- rewrite to application root -->
                <action type="Rewrite" url="<%= process.env.BASE_URL %>" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The `BASE_URL` variable itself is defined in a `.env.production` file in same folder as `vue.config.js` as described [here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58703965). It is a plain text file that contains simply:

```
BASE_URL="/my-vroot-name/"
```

With the above, your standard `yarn build` command will perform variable substitution in your `src\web.config` template and write the output to `dist\web.config`.

When setting up your IIS virtual application, make sure your physical path points to the `dist` folder, or adjust the `BASE_URL` and `HtmlWebpackPlugin2` output `filename` paths as needed for your server environment.